# How to manage the histogram of an `rcauchy()` in R?

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

`rcauchy()` is a fairly bad-behaving distribution whose histogram visualization is difficult.

I was wondering how I could improve the histogram presentation of `rcauchy()` below?

More specifically, is there a way I could show 80% or 90% of the entire distribution in the histogram?

```
x = rcauchy(5e4)

hist(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to plot the middle of your distribution, just subset your sample.

```
cuts <- quantile(x, c(.1,.9))
hist(x[x>=cuts[1] & x<=cuts[2]])
```